# How can I turn off screen on remote computer with LogMeIn?

Tags: remote-desktop, logmein

I'm using log me in to remotely connect to a computer, however, when I do so, the screen turns on (its a laptop, so no chance of physically unplugging it), and if people are where the computer is, they can see what I do (and even mess with the computer!).

This caught me off guard the first time I realized it was happening, since I was used to Remote Desktop functionality, where the computer being access gets locked (and thats what I was expecting).

I've dig through the options, but I can seem to find something to get this done.. anybody knows how?

Comment: Are you not using Remote Desktop now?  I've used Hamachi (LogMeIn) for a few years now, and I always just use Remote Desktop.  The remote console is locked, as you expected, thus no one is viewing or messing with my session from the remote end.

Comment: Ha! I had tried hamachi before and I could connect from home to work but not the other way.. today I decided to try again and duh! I had forgotten to accept remote connections in my Laptop! You would have gotten the answer if you had post it as one! (you still can though!)

Comment: Just a note, it is not wise to completely close the lid of an operating laptop. It could overheat, or at least the fans will "roar" unnecessarily, causing wear and tear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You can no longer change this locally while sitting at the host computer - you can only make the change while in a Remote Control session to the host computer. During the session, on the black toolbar/ribbon that runs along the top of the Remote Control window, click Options, and you will see "Lock keyboard" and "Blank screen."

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually turn the screen off or even leave it on standby because when you move the mouse it will come out again.

But what you could try is turn the brightness down. It's not the most elegant solution but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there *is* an elegant solution which doesn't involve closing laptop lids or dimming displays.

All versions of Logmein (including Free) fully support the following features:

- Lock host keyboard and mouse
- Blank host screen

The "Black Screen" option requires the installation of a DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling) driver, which only takes about 5-10 seconds. After that, you can turn the screen on and off at will. The screen will instantly go into power save mode (i.e. the power LED changes colour/blinks etc.) The screen isn't just black, but completely off.

I've been using these features for two years at least - it's nothing new, and works perfectly.

You have to customize your LogMeIn toolbar to get these options to appear.

See the below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Talked with LogMeIn their software does not support keeping the screen blank if your display on the host reaches it's "turn off display" time or computer goes to sleep.

Either set it to a longer time on the host or if you are away from you client for a certain period of time while connected to the host. Upon return uncheck blank screen and check blank screen again, which should turn it on.