# vnc with ability to black the screen?

Tags: vnc

I am accessing a computer elsewhere in the house that is on black screensaver.. i'd like to be able to access it without the screen changing.

From time to time I just need to access it and save some open unsaved documents, but i'd like to retain a black screen.

suggestions involving other remote viewing apps are welcome..

black screen is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logmein can be set to do that.  Have a look at this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/92365/how-can-i-turn-off-screen-on-remote-computer-with-logmein).

Comment: Logmein sounds like it might be inefficient, though i'll give it a look.  I'd rather a local connection not over the internet.

Comment: I use it all the time myself and would rather use it than vnc as the performance is excellent on a decent connection and there's some very convenient features.

Comment: @dkwiebe http://i53.tinypic.com/2hhk3lh.jpg  does it look like this for you? judging by that, it may be ok for launching apps.. but for typing into a notepad window i don't think so.

Comment: @dkwiebe also I don't like the idea of a computer being available over the internet unnecessary.   so i'd prefer a better solution, but yours and your ref to that question, is a solution.

Comment: @dkwiebe looks like jumanx's solution, mentioned in the question you linked to, is v good for me.. at this time, without a vnc solution.. or local solution.. but he mentions a blanking monitor solution too.. and it's good to know of your solution too..

Comment: @barlop  I'm glad to know that works.

Comment: @dkwiebe I don't want to know if you're glad. This is not a therapy group or an outlet for men to display emotion or show their feminine side.  This is a website with a growing collection of questions and answers. That's all, and that's good.

Comment: @dkwiebe You failed to correct an error in the comments.. the pic I linked to did not how it should be. Must be some resolution issue. I'm looking at an 800x600 screen now and it's fine. Logmein is very good.. V fast and easy to install too. No restart necessary. A Computer can just be made ready, easily. viewing and file transfer are available.  Fine for typing into notepad